# High, Low, High/Low season formula in dates

Tags: date, validation, google-sheets, calculation

Is there a formula where I can calculate [amount of days between arrival date and departure date], an arrival and departure date in high, low, or partly high/low dates. So I have a column with an arrival date and a column with a departure date where the days in between could be in a high, low or even crossover season. 'high and low crossover': meaning if a person stays certain days in low season and certain days in high season where another price is needed to pay.

I have added a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFYWduydJACvxGT88u1yOvAmRsfsiYoCg6ySGP3XuwA/edit?usp=sharing) to the sheet. In the Data sheet I made a calendar where I had the Low and High Season marked. Maybe this reference can be used to calculate. Vlookup and Countif maybe?

So basically I only need column "I" and "J" calculated from the columns "G" and "H".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formulas to calculate number of days in Low, ie. High season:

- `=countif(arrayformula(vlookup(SEQUENCE(int(H3)-int(G3);1;int(G3));Data!$A:$F;6;false));"Low")`
- `=countif(arrayformula(vlookup(SEQUENCE(int(H3)-int(G3);1;int(G3));Data!$A:$F;6;false));"High")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Goran, however should the low season days be 12? because it already calculates correctly the night of the Aug. 31st to Sept. 1st - so it calculate the nights.
Going from low season to high season should be adjusted likewise.

Comment: in that case, use SEQUENCE(H3-G3;..) instead of SEQUENCE(H3-G3+1;..). I updated the formulas in the answer above

Comment: Sorry our messages crossed... however J 4 and I 5 should calculate 1 night. See my sheet updated.

Comment: it is caused by G4 having a time part (2021/08/07 16:02:38). Either delete the time part, or wrap G and H cells in int(). as I did in the updated formulas in my answer

Comment: OK sorry I wrote it wasn't working but I still had time inserted.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uwWa4506U9qcuMZCGW4aKnma58bNncnEpiHr_mtF1vg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, it's because I formated the script wrong to auto include first date. 
I'll figure it out from here...
Thank you VERY MUCH for your help.
Much appreciated.